# SQL Server : must declare scalar variables error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have build a function and currently I'm getting error that scalar variables is not define

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure F_FindGLAccountParent, Line 65 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@CurrentGlCode".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure F_FindGLAccountParent, Line 71 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@CurrentGlCode".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure F_FindGLAccountParent, Line 93 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@CurrentGlCode".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure F_FindGLAccountParent, Line 100 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@CurrentGlCode".

Can someone help to fix this issue?

This is my query

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [BIEDW].[F_FindGLAccountParent] 
    (@sChildGLAccountNumber varchar(6),
     @sParentGLAccountNumber varchar(6),
     @dSearchDate date)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentGLCode varchar(8)
    SELECT @CurrentGLCode = @sChildGLAccountNumber
 
    DECLARE @ReturnValue int
    SELECT @ReturnValue = NULL
 
    -- if we are to search at currently effective GL hierarchy    
    IF @dSearchDate IS NULL 
    BEGIN    
        -- if the child GL exists
        IF EXISTS (SELECT GL_ACCOUNT_COD FROM BIEDW.EDW_GL_ACCOUNT 
                   WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @sChildGLAccountNumber 
                     AND EFF_REC_FLAG = 'Y' 
                     AND DEFINITION_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @ReturnValue = 0

            -- get the child account code to search for parent
            SELECT @CurrentGLCode = GL_ACCOUNT_COD 
            FROM BIEDW.EDW_GL_ACCOUNT 
            WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @sChildGLAccountNumber 
              AND EFF_REC_FLAG = 'Y' 
              AND DEFINITION_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
        
            -- while there are parents to look in the hierarchy and 
            -- that we still haven't found the account that we search
            WHILE ISNULL(@CurrentGlCode, '') <> '' AND @ReturnValue = 0 
            BEGIN
                -- get the next parent
                SELECT @CurrentGLCode = GL_ACCOUNT_PARENT_COD 
                FROM BIEDW.EDW_GL_ACCOUNT 
                WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_COD = @CurrentGLCode 
                  AND EFF_REC_FLAG = 'Y' 
                  AND DEFINITION_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'

                --check if it is the GL that we are looking for
                IF ISNULL(@CurrentGlCode, '') <> '' 
                   AND RIGHT(@CurrentGLCode, LEN(@CurrentGLCode) - 2) = @sParentGLAccountNumber 
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @ReturnValue = 1
                END
            END
        END
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        -- if the child GL exists
        IF EXISTS (SELECT GL_ACCOUNT_COD FROM BIEDW.EDW_GL_ACCOUNT 
                   WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @sChildGLAccountNumber 
                     AND @dSearchDate BETWEEN EFF_START_DT AND ISNULL(EFF_END_DT, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE))
                     AND DEFINITION_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y') 
        BEGIN
            -- get the child account code to search for parent
            SELECT @CurrentGLCode = GL_ACCOUNT_COD 
            FROM BIEDW.EDW_GL_ACCOUNT 
            WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @sChildGLAccountNumber 
              AND @dSearchDate BETWEEN EFF_START_DT AND ISNULL(EFF_END_DT, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE))
              AND DEFINITION_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
        
            SELECT @ReturnValue = 0

            -- while there are parents to look in the hierarchy and 
            -- that we still haven't found the account that we search
            WHILE ISNULL(@CurrentGlCode, '') <> '' AND @ReturnValue = 0 
            BEGIN
                -- get the next parent
                SELECT @CurrentGLCode = GL_ACCOUNT_PARENT_COD 
                FROM BIEDW.EDW_GL_ACCOUNT 
                WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_COD = @CurrentGLCode 
                  AND @dSearchDate BETWEEN EFF_START_DT AND ISNULL(EFF_END_DT, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE))
                  AND DEFINITION_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'

                -- check if it is the GL that we are looking for
                IF ISNULL(@CurrentGlCode,'') <> '' 
                   AND RIGHT(@CurrentGLCode, LEN(@CurrentGLCode) - 2) = @sParentGLAccountNumber 
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @ReturnValue = 1
                END
            END
        END    
    END
 
    RETURN @ReturnValue
END
```

Currently I am not understanding why I get errors that variables are not declared

Comment: Case sensitive? `CurrentGLCode` <> `CurrentGlCode`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you just go and bin that function, I'm afraid; it'll performed **awfully**. Multi-line scalar functions can perform poorly (especially when they can't be inlined, which the above certainly won't be able to be), and `WHILE` loops *do* perform poorly. You would be far better off explaining the goal you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: Is your sql server running on a windows server or on a linux ? In case of linux than it will indeed be a case sensitive problem is suggested already

Comment: @GuidoG, the OS doesn't control case-sensitivity of T-SQL variables, the SQL Server server collation does.

Comment: I daily drive SQL Server at home on several Linux hosts, @GuidoG , I can confirm that that statement is not true. The OS and the case sensitivity of the SQL have no relation at all.

Comment: Also just a raised eyebrows observation: who on earth named the column `GL_ACCOUNT_COD` instead of `GL_ACCOUNT_CODE`?

Comment: it was a case sensitive issues.Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Larnu Did you altered some setting ? I have a Sql Server running on linux and one thing that annoys me is that it is case sensitive.

Comment: Nope, @GuidoG . I've probably installed 5 or 6 instances on Linux, and all start as case insensitive with the default settings.

Comment: @DanGuzman Then why is my sql server running on my linux case sensitive ?

Comment: @Larnu Interesting, from where did you download this sql server ? I want that to

Comment: You don't "download" SQL Server for Linux in the traditional sense, @GuidoG , you install it via the package manager for the distribution; I use the official repositories.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I did it with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @GuidoG, I expect `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation');` will return a case-sensitive collation if variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: @GuidoG, the collation with a Linux install is specified via `mssql-conf setup`.